# Override django setting only if present in os.environ

Tags: python, django

I want to define a function that will create a variable under certain circumstances at the scope of where the function was invoked.

Something like this:

```
def hook_env(new_var_name, env_var_name):
    if env_var_name in os.environ:
        "define new_var_name at the scope in which this function was defined and set it equal to os.environ[env_var_name]"
```

My use case is so I can override Django settings from environment variables, but only present in the environment.

Something like this is invalid

```
    # only create the variable if some criteria is met
    def hook_env(new_var, env_name):
         if env_name in os.environ:
             global()[new_var] = os.environ[env_name]
```

In C/C++ I might use a macro. I don't know what to do in python.

Would it be safe to modify the default variable wherever django creates it in the first place (`django/conf/global_settings.py`) from inside my settings file?

Comment: "_Something like this is invalid_" Why? Doesn't that already do what you want (The settings **are** defined in the global scope)? Also is there a reason you can't simply use something like: `new_var = os.environ.get(env_name, "Some default")`

Comment: In `new_var = os.getenv(env_name, magic)` I need `magic`, since the settings are not already imported. For example, `SERVER_EMAIL = os.getenv('SERVER_EMAIL', SERVER_EMAIL)` in a django settings file will raise a NameError exception.

Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/settings/) specifically say not to import  `django.conf.global_settings`: "Note that a settings file should not import from global_settings, because that’s redundant."

Comment: `SERVER_EMAIL = os.getenv('SERVER_EMAIL', SERVER_EMAIL)` presumes you have set the value for `SERVER_EMAIL` before this line of course... The second argument to `getenv` is supposed to be the default value to use if the environment variable isn't there if you specify a variable that doesn't exist yet over there obviously you'll get a `NameError`... And why are we even talking about importing the settings when we're configuring them here?

Comment: My use case is that I don't know whether some environment variables are defined in my dev/prod environments. If they are undefined, I want to use Django's default by just not defining the variable in my settings file. This can be achieved by `if 'SOME_ENV_VAR' in os.environ: SOME_ENV_VAR = os.environ['SOME_ENV_VAR']` but this has the same token `SOME_ENV_VAR` in 3 places, which I am not crazy about.